# Google maps api custom marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-maps-markers

I am looking for good tourtial or solution for custom marker from xml file (RelativeLayout).

I have:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lay"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:src="@drawable/custom_marker" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num_txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="20"
    android:textColor="#ce8223"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

How I can use it as marker?

Comment: You can't. Markers are images on both Maps V1 and Maps V2. Are you referring to some other mapping solution?

Comment: I have one map. I can put two markers with number.
It is my problem.

Comment: Create a bitmap at runtime with the number, by drawing to a `Bitmap`-backed `Canvas`.

Comment: Another solution may be to use a `LevelListDrawable` for the numbers, wrapped in a `LayerListDrawable` to add the marker background. Yet another solution, if the number of numbers is small, is to just have a bunch of bitmaps already set up with the right numbers as resources. No, I do not have an example handy of drawing to a `Canvas`, sorry.

Comment: tnx, the second solution is bad for my aplication unfortunately.
How can I use this first solutino.
Marker.setBackground() ? Marker.setNumber()?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#change_the_default_marker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is some kind of workaround to turn your layout into `Drawable` which can be used as a marker image:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight()); 

view.buildDrawingCache();
//EDIT: updated drawable creation
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), view.getDrawingCache().copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true)); //this drawable can be used as a marker

// **** EDIT2: don't forget to set bounds to your drawable
d.setBounds(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

As you might understand, you need to store `Context` pointer in order to obtain `LayoutInflater`

Hope it helps

Comment: 01-16 18:57:56.254: E/AndroidRuntime(1110): java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@40544700

Comment: how change text on textview for items?

Comment: updated my answer with `setBounds` call. As for changing text, you can use following: `TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.num_txt);    text.setText("Custom text");`. Insert that before `buildDrawingCache()` call